# Moving my site from one domain name to another isn't working, despite correct DNS lookup

Tags: domain-name-system, godaddy, 1and1

*Warning: I have no expertise in these matters, so I'm really sorry if this is a stupid question or I've missed some info you need to be able to diagnose the problem.*

I'm trying to make changes to my 1&1 server so the site is hosted at **totomerch.net**, rather than totomerch.com where it's been until now. The server IP is 87.106.250.29

Totomerch.net is registered with Godaddy, and has a single @ record pointing at 87.106.250.29. It's been over 72 hours since I made this change.

In my 1&1 control panel, 87.106.250.29 is mapped to totomerch.net, and when I do a reverse lookup (http://remote.12dt.com/lookup.php) it resolves correctly to totomerch.net

Yet when I visit totomerch.net (or any sub-page) in a browser, it immediately redirects to totomerch.com

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you created a redirect on Godaddy, or there is no vhost configured on your server for the .net domain.

Edit: Just checked DNS, and your www.totomerch.net is still pointing to your .com

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.totomerch.net.             IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.totomerch.net.      3600    IN      CNAME   www.totomerch.com.
www.totomerch.com.      3600    IN      A       31.222.178.121
```

Possible that you also have a redirect from just the domain name to www.
In this case, all requests will still be served by the .com domain/vhost

Answer (score 0):

In your Apache 2.2.14 webserver you configured a 301 redirect to http://www.totomech.com. So everything works as configured.

Answer (score 0):

For me your .net domain is resolving correctly to the IP address stated however you have a 301 redirect configured

```
wget -v http://totomerch.net
--2011-08-04 10:36:41--  http://totomerch.net/
Resolving totomerch.net... 87.106.250.29
Connecting to totomerch.net|87.106.250.29|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.totomerch.com/ [following]
--2011-08-04 10:36:41--  http://www.totomerch.com/
Resolving www.totomerch.com... 31.222.178.121
Connecting to www.totomerch.com|31.222.178.121|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
```